# Python: IMPORT ADI in Intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, libraries, rtl-sdr

I bought a PlutoSDR and I am running Windows 10. I do not know how to import adi into my IDE in Windows. (Linux VM works)

---

**Non-essential background. Can Skip to Bottom:**

- I upgraded my firmware on the Pluto
- I installed the driver

  - https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/plutosdr-m2k-drivers-win/releases/download/v0.7/PlutoSDR-M2k-USB-Drivers.exe,
- And installed the libiio library

  - libiio-0.21.g565bf68-Windows-setup.exe I then tested the install, and
    I was able to ping 192.168.2.1

I also got output from  `C:\> iio_info -s`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>iio_info -s
Library version: 0.21 (git tag: 565bf68)
Compiled with backends: xml ip usb serial
Unable to create Local IIO context : Function not implemented
Available contexts:
0: 0456:b673 (Analog Devices Inc. PlutoSDR (ADALM-PLUTO)), serial=1044739659930006f4ff24003edc27135f [usb:3.9.5]
```

At this point, I do not know if the comment "`Unable to create Local IIO contest: ...`" is a problem, but I continued anyway.

I then ran the command: `C:\> iio_info -u ip:192.168.2.1`

```
Library version: 0.21 (git tag: 565bf68)
Compiled with backends: xml ip usb serial
IIO context created with network backend.
Backend version: 0.18 (git tag: v0.18 )
Backend description string: 192.168.2.1 Linux (none) 4.14.0-42540-g387d584 #301 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 3 15:06:53 CEST 2019 armv7l
IIO context has 9 attributes:
hw_model: Analog Devices PlutoSDR Rev.B (Z7010-AD9364)
hw_model_variant: 0
hw_serial: 1044739659930006f4ff24003edc27135f
fw_version: v0.31
ad9361-phy,xo_correction: 39999954
ad9361-phy,model: ad9364
local,kernel: 4.14.0-42540-g387d584
ip,ip-addr: 192.168.2.1
uri: ip:192.168.2.1
IIO context has 5 devices:
iio:device0: adm1177
2 channels found:
voltage0: (input)
2 channel-specific attributes found:
attr 0: raw value: 777
attr 1: scale value: 6.433105468
current0: (input)
2 channel-specific attributes found:
attr 0: raw value: 797
attr 1: scale value: 0.516601562
No trigger on this device
iio:device1: ad9361-phy
9 channels found:
altvoltage1: TX_LO (output)
8 channel-specific attributes found:
attr 0: external value: 0
attr 1: fastlock_load value: 0
attr 2: fastlock_recall ERROR: Invalid argument (-22)
attr 3: fastlock_save value: 0 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
attr 4: fastlock_store value: 0
attr 5: frequency value: 2449999998
attr 6: frequency_available value: [46875001 1 6000000000]
attr 7: powerdown value: 0
voltage0: (input)
15 channel-specific attributes found:
attr 0: bb_dc_offset_tracking_en value: 1
attr 1: filter_fir_en value: 0
attr 2: gain_control_mode value: slow_attack
attr 3: gain_control_mode_available value: manual fast_attack slow_attack hybrid
attr 4: hardwaregain value: 71.000000 dB
attr 5: hardwaregain_available value: [-3 1 71]
attr 6: quadrature_tracking_en value: 1
attr 7: rf_bandwidth value: 18000000
attr 8: rf_bandwidth_available value: [200000 1 56000000]
attr 9: rf_dc_offset_tracking_en value: 1
attr 10: rf_port_select value: A_BALANCED
attr 11: rf_port_select_available value: A_BALANCED B_BALANCED C_BALANCED A_N A_P B_N B_P C_N C_P TX_MONITOR1 TX_MONITOR2 TX_MONITOR1_2
attr 12: rssi value: 114.25 dB
attr 13: sampling_frequency value: 30720000
attr 14: sampling_frequency_available value: [2083333 1 61440000]
voltage3: (output)
8 channel-specific attributes found:
attr 0: filter_fir_en value: 0
attr 1: raw value: 306
attr 2: rf_bandwidth value: 18000000
attr 3: rf_bandwidth_available value: [200000 1 40000000]
attr 4: rf_port_select_available value: A B
attr 5: sampling_frequency value: 30720000
attr 6: sampling_frequency_available value: [2083333 1 61440000]
attr 7: scale value: 1.000000
altvoltage0: RX_LO (output)
8 channel-specific attributes found:
attr 0: external value: 0   ............
```

There is a lot more output, but I will truncate it here.

At this point, I am assuming the Pluto will work on my Windows machine.

---

**Essential Information:**

I then take to my IDE and import the libraries for `matplotlib` and `numpy` by using File > Project Structure > SDKs > Packages

I am able to find all the basic libraries, but not `adi`.

I assume I have to import a repository, but unsure where to gather it. I did, however, include https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio.git/ in my repo list. I still had no luck importing adi.

I currently have two questions:

1. Is there a repository I must add to be able to import this library
   to my IDE?
2. Is "`Unable to create Local IIO context : Function not implemented...`" problematic?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the above drivers I was able to File > Project Structure > SDKs > Packages and install `pyadi-iio`

I can now `import adi`